# Can't enable Remote Desktop in Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Operating system: Windows 7 Professional

I have Remote Desktop enabled in Remote Settings (Start -> Right-click Computer -> Properties -> Remote Settings).  It's saying that I need to enable the Windows Firewall exception for Remote Desktop.

So I went into Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall.  I pressed "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall".  I didn't see Remote Desktop in the list of programs, however.  I've tried adding mstsc.exe to the list of allowed programs, but that didn't solve the problem.  I think that's because mstsc.exe is the remote desktop client, not server.

I feel like this may be happening because of software I installed.  Is there a way around this?  Is there another way to enable Remote Desktop in allowed programs in Windows Firewall?

Comment: Remote Desktop should automatically open the hole in Windows Firewall for you, once enabled.  Are you running another firewall/security program?  Is this a personal computer, or part of a corporate network?

Comment: It's a personal computer.  It's not on a domain.

Comment: One thing I should note: Remote Desktop *worked* for awhile after a fresh install of Windows 7.  Then, after installing some software, it stopped working.  I'm installing a virtual windows 7 and gonna install the same software to find out exactly what's causing it to stop working.

Comment: I found the culprit.  It's Panasonic's FPWIN PRO 6.3.  Now, I wonder if there's a way to fix all the damage it did to Windows Firewall, or if I'm stuck reformatting.

Comment: mstsc.exe is the remote desktop ***client***, it has nothing to do with inbound connections. You need to open the connection for the Remote Desktop ***Session Host***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by going Start -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and creating a new Inbound rule for port 3389.  The rule still isn't showing up in the list, however, but it is active.

Just a friendly warning!  Watch out for Panasonic FPWIN Pro 6.3! It will trash your firewall rules.

Comment: So you do not have a item called ["Remote Desktop (TCP-In)"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5FjEY.png) What edition of Windows 7 are you using?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Only certain versions of Windows 7 can host a remote connection.  All versions can connect to a host.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, Sam's question is about hosting, that's why I asked him what edition he is using.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Professional.